# Issue faced during the implementation of the regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

**Scenario:**

The regex expression that I have tried shouldn't allow the expression containing '@' character. And I have successfully implemented it. But, it should contain '.' dot-symbol mandatory between two characters.

**Issue Faced:**

This regex expression is allowing the characters without the '.' dot-symbol.

**Here is the regex expression:**

```
 ^([a-z0-9]*([.])*([a-z0-9]))+(?!@)(?!gmail.com)+$
```

**Required Outcome:**

**1. The above regex expression should allow the following expressions:**

a. john.mayor

b. michael.clarke

c. jitendra123.gurung

and so on.

**2. But it shouldn't allow the following expressions:**

a. john

b. jitendra@

c. john@gmail.com

and so on.

**What correction do I need in the regex expression that I have tried above to achieve the desired outcome?**

*Suggestions are highly appreciated.*

Comment: what about `^\w+[.]\w+$`?

Comment: I have already tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: what did this capture that it was not supposed to?

Comment: You know that `(?!@)(?!gmail.com)+$` is pointless and could be replaced by just `$`?

Comment: It is also useful part of my validation case because the expression shouldn't contain @ symbols.

Comment: @Onyambu Let me test your suggested case once again. It may work.

Comment: @DixonCh No it's pointless, as those lookaheads check for things that can't be in that place - as you require the end of the string next. `^([a-z0-9]*([.])*([a-z0-9]))+$` would do exactly the same as your expression. And by turning both `*` into `+` you would even solve your question (though Onyambus suggestion is way more concise)

Comment: You were right. I did some more testing for the required case. And I found the suggestion of the @Onyambu concise too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the character class `[a-z0-9]+` that you specified and match that one or more times using `+` to make sure that there is at least one of `[a-z0-9]` before and after the dot.

[`^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1kvE4c/1)

Answer (score 0):

I have found two most relevant answers as suggested by @Onyambu and @Theforthbird which I have posted below:

1. `^\w+[.]\w+$` as suggested by @Onyambu
2. `^(?!.*@)[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$` as suggested by @Theforthbird

Both meets my required validation. Let me know which one is better.

Comment: I have updated my answer without the `(?!.*@)` because that should not be there because `[a-z0-9]` does not match an `@`. `\w` matches upper and lowercase characters as well as an underscore so it is just a mattter of what exactly you allow to match.

Comment: If its so, then I think your suggestion meets my requirement more. But the expression that I need shouldn't contain '@' symbol so, there should be (?!.*@) as well.

Comment: Does this part i.e. (?!.*@) checks the occurrence of the '@' symbol throughout the expression and doesn't let it to occur?

Comment: That is not needed because the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-z0-9]` does not match an `@` so if there is an `@` in your string, the regex will not match.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the suggestion.